# How to convert text into columns in java

Tags: java

I have the following string:

```
Time Point 
    CH4 
    H2 


    0   2   36
    20  1   49
    40  1   44
    60  1   85
    80  1   106
    100 1   117
    120 1   117
    140 1   113
    160 2   131
    180 2   153
```

I want the three lines at the top to be each of the column headers so the result is as displayed in the console.

```
Time Point CH4  H2 
        0   2   36
        20  1   49
        40  1   44
        60  1   85
        80  1   106
        100 1   117
        120 1   117
        140 1   113
        160 2   131
        180 2   153
```

Sometimes there are more than three columns  but there are always the same number of strings as columns.

How can this be done in java?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly are you having trouble with? Is the source a string, array, file? Are you outputting to the console or a file? Please provide more details.

Comment: from where are you reading your data and where are you writing it to?

Comment: The input is a string. The output is the console